# I'm trying to write a method that returns true if a specified value exists in a given row. But this code says it's out of bound. How do I fix this?

Tags: java

```
public static boolean hasValue(int[][] arr, int value, int row)
{
    int column = arr[row].length; 
    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) 
    { 
        if (arr[row][i] == value) 
        return true; 

    } 
    return false;
}
```

It's a boolean method, so if the given value exist in a given row, it will say true.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

Comment: What does your `int[][]` array look like?

Comment: I am under the impression that you have forgotten that arrays are 0 indexed.

Comment: your for loop should be fine..  but are you sure the value you pass in for row is in bounds?  test for 0 <= row < arr.length

Comment: Please read the help about providing a minimum, small, verifiable example. That is, a complete program that has the bug you're trying to fix. Then people will be able to help you. Otherwise, we're just guessing.